# Databinding msg Cannot find a setter for \u003candroid.webkit.WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android-webview, retrofit2, android-mvvm

After changing TextView to WebView in android studio I'm getting error,

```
[databinding] {"msg":"Cannot find a setter for \u003candroid.webkit.WebView
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/purple_700"
    tools:context=".activities.PostDetailsActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/textContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ubuntu_regular"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:text="@{content}"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```